A manifold whose tangent space is a sum of line bundles and higher rank vector bundles
I am looking for an example of the following situation. Let $M$ be a connected (if possible compact) manifold such that its tangent bundle $T(M)$ admits a vector bundle decomposition
$$
T(M) = A \oplus L_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus L_k, ~~~ k > 0,
$$
where each summand $L_i$ is a line bundle over $M$, and $A$ is a vector bundle that cannot be written as a direct sum of line bundles. If $M$ admitted a nice (compact) group action then that would be even better.

Is K supposed to be L? Also, should I assume k>0?

yes, it is now fixed.

I guess in your  question you   implicitly want  that the  splitting  is preserved by group action. yes?

You are asking about manifolds whose projective span is equal to $k$, according to the main definition of Grant and Schutte - Projective span of Wall manifolds.
Any manifold with zero Euler characteristic gives an example with $k>0$, but you'll find many more interesting examples in the cited preprint.

Remark:  I assume that you want $A$ to be a non-trivial bundle.  Otherwise, of course, any parallelizable compact manifold would be an example.  In particular, any compact Lie group would be an example with a nice compact group action.
A simple interesting example is $S^5$, whose tangent bundle can be written as the sum of a line bundle and an irreducible 4-plane bundle.  It also has a nice compact group action, as $\mathrm{SO}(6)$ acts transitively on it in the obvious way.
The proof of this is as follows:  First, $S^5$ is an odd dimensional sphere, so it has a nonvanishing tangent vector field.  Hence $TS^5 = L_1 \oplus A$ where $L_1$ is a trivial line bundle and $A$ is a 4-plane bundle.  It remains to show that $A$ is irreducible.  First, $A$ cannot contain any non-trivial line bundle $L_2$ since $L_2$ would have to be orientable (since $S^5$ is simply connected) and hence trivial, and a non-vanishing section of such an $L_2$ would yield a tangent vector field on $S^5$ that is linearly independent from any non-vanishing section of $L_1$.  However, as is well-known, $S^5$ cannot have two linearly independent tangent vector fields.  Second, $A$ cannot split as the sum of two $2$-plane bundles since $H^2(S^5,Z)$ is trivial, so any $2$-plane bundle over $S^5$ must be trivial and hence a sum of two (trivial) line bundles.  Hence, if $A$ could be written as the sum of two $2$-plane bundles, $S^5$ would have to be parallelizable, which, we know, it is not.  Thus, $A$ is irreducible.

However the  tangent bundle of $S^5$ is  not decompossible in the way you mentioned but according to the  Splitting principal there is  an space $X$ and continuous map  $f:X\to S^5$  such that $f^$ is an isomorphism in K theory and  the pull back  $f^(TS^5)$ of the  tangent  bundle of  $S^5$  is decomposed to  direct sum of line bundle. In this  case  s  there an explicit (compact) manifold $X$  with this property?What is theminimum possible dimension for such  manifold $X$? By this question I search for a possible  smooth version of  splitting principle in K theory

I just  ask  this  question and its  extension here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475457/smooth-version-of-the-splitting-principle

In this  example  I think  the  plane  $A$ is the  pull back of the  real tangent bundle of  $\mathbb{C}P^2$  under the  fiber map $S^5 \to \mathbb{C}P^2$. The tangent bundle of  CP^2 is irreducible but it apparently  does not implies that the  bundle A you mentioned is irreducible. So  this is  a  motivation to ask: What is  an example  of  principle bundle $X\to B$ where $A$ is a  connection plane tangent to X  such that $TB$ is irreducible  but A is  not? I  would  appreciate if  you  give  comment on this  question

@AliTaghavi:  A simple example, is to let $X = S^3$ and $B=S^2$ and let $\pi:S^3\to S^2$ be the Hopf map.  The tangent bundle to $S^2$ is irreducible over $S^2$, but the pullback via $\pi$ is trivial over $S^3$.

Thank you very much for your answer

The product of a 2-sphere with a torus is an example. There are complex analytic examples due to Beauville (Complex manifolds with split tangent bundle). Every 3-manifold has trivial tangent bundle, so we could use a product of a torus, a 3-manifold, and a 2-sphere.

Doesnt the sphere times torus have a trivial tangent bundle?

@ThomasRot: yes, sorry, that's right. But Beauville's examples are nice complex analytic examples.
